# Scala - ListBuffer emptying itself after every add in loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to add a number of objects to a Scala ListBuffer in a loop, but every time I add one it disappears on the next iteration of the loop.

When I print the contents of the ListBuffer before and after adding a new entry, I get the following output:

> Before add: ListBuffer()
>
> After add: ListBuffer(com.me.FeatureV2@20d953ba)
>
> Before add: ListBuffer()
>
> After add: ListBuffer(com.me.FeatureV2@6b768ce7)
>
> Before add: ListBuffer()
>
> After add: ListBuffer(com.me.FeatureV2@123f42d5)

Code:

```
def generateStatistics(df: DataFrame): List[FeatureV2] = {
    var features = ListBuffer[FeatureV2]()
    val dataColumn = "data"
    for (field <- df.schema.fieldNames){
      val columnType: String = df.select(field).dtypes(0)._2

      if (columnType == StringType.toString){
        val statsDf: DataFrame = getStats(df, field, dataColumn)
        for (row <- statsDf){
          println("Before add: " + features)
          val feature = new FeatureV2()
          feature.element = row.getString(0)
          feature.count = row.getLong(1)
          feature.sum = row.getDouble(2)
          feature.max = row.getDouble(3)
          feature.min = row.getDouble(4)
          feature.feature = field
          features += feature
          println("After add: " + features)
        }
      }
    }
    features.toList
  }
```

On occasion however, I get the following:

> Before add: ListBuffer()
>
> After add: ListBuffer(com.me.FeatureV2@1433183c)
>
> Before add: ListBuffer(com.me.FeatureV2@1433183c)
>
> After add: ListBuffer(com.me.FeatureV2@1433183c,
>   com.me.FeatureV2@4b0df9e5)
>
> Before add: ListBuffer()
>
> After add: ListBuffer(com.me.FeatureV2@1e201b19)

This looks like it actually is populating the ListBuffer, but it's being cleared out. Something to do with garbage collection?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling ``generateStatistics`` only once?

Comment: @JeanLogeart Yes, definitely.

Comment: On a side note, please use ListBuffer as a val and append to it using += ([see here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html)). This is just weird and hard to reason about because you're modifying the object reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `for (row <- statsDf)` to `for (row <- statsDf.collect())`.

If this fixes your problem, then your issues may be caused by the fact that `foreach` is running in one or more threads.

`for (row <- stadsDf)` is the actually calling `DataFrame.foreach(f: Row => Unit)`, which is a distributed `foreach`  where `f` may run on any number of threads or machines depending on your Spark master.

Answer (score 2):

A Spark application is made up of a driver and executors. You control and create things from the Driver -- the executors get copies of variables that were in scope. So, the executors get copies of the `ListBuffer`. They append to their copies, which are lost when the task completes.

You could use `collect()` to pull the data into the driver to append to the `ListBuffer` there, or use broadcast variables.

See **[the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables)** for a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

is the collection mutable?

also, when using Scala one should make an effort in doing FP.

```
df.schema.fieldNames.map {...}
```

would probably do the work you need. And since you have an `if` maybe a `collect` would be more appropriated